# Arrowhead offset

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm a relatively new to Mathematica and I am currently trying to make a Hasse-Diagram. However, I am struggling to get the arrowheads right:

```
   Graph[{{M1, W1} -> {M1, M2, W1, W2}, {M1, W2} -> {M1, M2, W1, 
    W2}, {M1, W3} -> {M1, M3, W3, W4}, {M1, W4} -> {M1, M3, W3, 
    W4}, {M2, W1} -> {M1, M2, W1, W2}, {M2, W1} -> {M2, M3, W1, 
    W2}, {M2, W2} -> {M1, M2, W1, W2}, {M2, W2} -> {M2, M3, W1, 
    W2}, {M2, W3} -> {M2, M3, W3, W4}, {M2, W4} -> {M2, M3, W3, 
    W4}, {M3, W1} -> {M2, M3, W1, W2}, {M3, W1} -> {M3, M4, W1, 
    W2}, {M3, W1} -> {M3, M4, W1, W3}, {M3, W1} -> {M3, M4, W1, 
    W4}, {M3, W2} -> {M2, M3, W1, W2}, {M3, W2} -> {M3, M4, W1, 
    W2}, {M3, W3} -> {M3, M4, W1, W3}, {M3, W3} -> {M2, M3, W3, 
    W4}, {M3, W3} -> {M1, M3, W3, W4}, {M3, W4} -> {M3, M4, W1, 
    W4}, {M3, W4} -> {M2, M3, W3, W4}, {M3, W4} -> {M1, M3, W3, 
    W4}, {M4, W1} -> {M3, M4, W1, W2}, {M4, W1} -> {M3, M4, W1, 
    W3}, {M4, W1} -> {M3, M4, W1, W4}, {M4, W2} -> {M3, M4, W1, 
    W2}, {M4, W3} -> {M3, M4, W1, W3}, {M4, W4} -> {M3, M4, W1, W4}},
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", DirectedEdges -> True, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Large, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> GraphElementData[{"Arrow", "ArrowSize" -> .01}]]
```

I have consulted the documentation and tried to adopt this in the code above, however the arrowheads, while being the right size will be too far away from the vertices. I would like them to touch the vertices. 
When I right-click the graph I can select different shapes of arrows. Selecting one of the presets then positions them correctly, yet now they will take on gargantuan forms.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the [`Arrowheads`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrowheads) setting by giving [`Graph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph) a [`BaseStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BaseStyle) option:

```
e = {{M1, W1} -> {M1, M2, W1, W2}, {M1, W2} -> {M1, M2, W1, 
    W2}, {M1, W3} -> {M1, M3, W3, W4}, {M1, W4} -> {M1, M3, W3, 
    W4}, {M2, W1} -> {M1, M2, W1, W2}, {M2, W1} -> {M2, M3, W1, 
    W2}, {M2, W2} -> {M1, M2, W1, W2}, {M2, W2} -> {M2, M3, W1, 
    W2}, {M2, W3} -> {M2, M3, W3, W4}, {M2, W4} -> {M2, M3, W3, 
    W4}, {M3, W1} -> {M2, M3, W1, W2}, {M3, W1} -> {M3, M4, W1, 
    W2}, {M3, W1} -> {M3, M4, W1, W3}, {M3, W1} -> {M3, M4, W1, 
    W4}, {M3, W2} -> {M2, M3, W1, W2}, {M3, W2} -> {M3, M4, W1, 
    W2}, {M3, W3} -> {M3, M4, W1, W3}, {M3, W3} -> {M2, M3, W3, 
    W4}, {M3, W3} -> {M1, M3, W3, W4}, {M3, W4} -> {M3, M4, W1, 
    W4}, {M3, W4} -> {M2, M3, W3, W4}, {M3, W4} -> {M1, M3, W3, 
    W4}, {M4, W1} -> {M3, M4, W1, W2}, {M4, W1} -> {M3, M4, W1, 
    W3}, {M4, W1} -> {M3, M4, W1, W4}, {M4, W2} -> {M3, M4, W1, 
    W2}, {M4, W3} -> {M3, M4, W1, W3}, {M4, W4} -> {M3, M4, W1, W4}};

Graph[
    e,
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
    DirectedEdges -> True, 
    VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
    VertexSize -> Large, 
    BaseStyle->{Arrowheads->.015}, 
    ImageSize->600
]
```

[image]

And a [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate) to explore the behavior as the size is varied:

```
Manipulate[
    Graph[
        e,
        PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
        DirectedEdges -> True, 
        VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
        VertexSize -> Large, 
        BaseStyle->{Arrowheads->size}, 
        ImageSize->600
    ],
    {{size, .015}, .005, .025}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Carl! That worked like a charm.